Exception when trying to query the schema in graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter
Is there some tracing I can add to understand what's going on?
I suddenly started getting the below exception when querying the schema. This was working fine before. The only change I can remember after last successful run is installing rosetta2 through homebrew. Could that cause issue?
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'graphql.ExecutionInput$Builder graphql.ExecutionInput$Builder.context(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)'
at io.leangen.graphql.util.ContextUtils.lambda$wrapContext$1(ContextUtils.java:13) ~[spqr-0.12.4.jar:na]
at graphql.ExecutionInput.transform(ExecutionInput.java:164) ~[graphql-java-22.0.jar:na]
at io.leangen.graphql.util.ContextUtils.wrapContext(ContextUtils.java:13) ~[spqr-0.12.4.jar:na]
at io.leangen.graphql.GraphQLRuntime$InputTransformer.instrumentExecutionInput(GraphQLRuntime.java:126) ~[spqr-0.12.4.jar:na]
at graphql.GraphQL.lambda$executeAsync$9(GraphQL.java:421) ~[graphql-java-22.0.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1187) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2341) ~[na:na]
at graphql.GraphQL.executeAsync(GraphQL.java:418) ~[graphql-java-22.0.jar:na]
at io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.HttpExecutor.lambda$execute$0(HttpExecutor.java:33) ~[graphql-spqr-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.1.jar:na]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4568) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar:3.6.6]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$DeferredResultSubscriber.connect(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:466) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler.handleValue(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:163) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:154) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]
I reverted all my changes and added a simple example for query and mutation.
It's always throwing that error and not able to query the schema.

spring dependencies was pulling graphql-java version 22 which is bad. graphql-java-version 21.5 is good. I just defined this in pom and problem solved. <graphql-java.version>21.5</graphql-java.version>
